# MCMS 2002 - How to implement redirection

Tags: .net, http-redirect, mcms-2000

Our company's website is built on MCMS 2002. We are on IIS6 and we need to redirect our site users to our new website in another domain. What are the options for redirection in MCMS 2002?

[mcmsfaq.com](http://www.mcmsfaq.com/samples/gdn.asp) has a link to a redirection control - reDirector, but the link is 404.

Will ISAPI_Rewrite work with MCSM-2002?

I urgently need hands-on advice on how to do this.

Thank you

Comment: @driis, no cause as far as I understand, MCMS intercepts requests to the server, which makes iis redirects impossible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Helicon Tech's ISAPI Rewrite. There's a lite (free) version over [here](http://www.helicontech.com/isapi_rewrite/). If you don't fancy regular expressions, you can simply create an ASPX with Response.Redirect.

Comment: I didn't get to try it, because we completely abandoned MCMS. Thank you for your sugestion though. I accept your answer, because this is the way we'd have gone if stuck with MCMS.